# AWS - Differentiate OSTYPE in Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, operating-system, rhel

I'm trying to write up a script to install tenable agents. It runs through a maintenance window every hour and will skip the install if the agent already exists. I currently have 2 tasks, one for RHEL and one for Amazon Linux 2, but RHEL for some reason keeps failing, so I wanted to swap the script for the linux one to just include RHEL.

The problem is, Amazon Linux and RHEL both spit back VERY similar information when using uname (`Linux`) and $OSTYPE (`linux-gnu`) But each needs a different Nessus file:

Amazon Linux 2 requires - "NessusAgent-8.2.0-amzn.x86_64.rpm" 
Redhat EL 8 requires - "NessusAgent-8.2.0-es8.x86_64.rpm"

Does anyone know of a good way to differentiate?

Here is what I have so far. I swapped the OSTYPE value to show what I need in place:

```
serviceName="nessusagent"

if systemctl --all --type service | grep -q "$serviceName";then
    echo "$serviceName exists."
else
    if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "Amazon Linux 2"* ]]; then
        wget "https://lmi-infosec-tenable.s3.amazonaws.com/NessusAgent-8.2.0-amzn.x86_64.rpm" -P /tmp/nessus/
        sudo rpm -ivh /tmp/nessus/NessusAgent-8.2.0-amzn.x86_64.rpm
        sudo /sbin/service nessusagent start
        sudo /opt/nessus_agent/sbin/nessuscli agent link --key=<key_value>--groups=<groups> --cloud
    else [[ "$OSTYPE" == "Redhat Enterprise Linux 8"* ]]; then
        mkdir /tmp/nessus/
        curl "https://lmi-infosec-tenable.s3.amazonaws.com/NessusAgent-8.2.0-es8.x86_64.rpm" --output /tmp/nessus/NessusAgent-8.2.0-es8.x86_64.rpm --silent
        sudo rpm -ivh /tmp/nessus/NessusAgent-8.2.0-es8.x86_64.rpm
        sudo /sbin/service nessusagent start
        sudo /opt/nessus_agent/sbin/nessuscli agent link --key=<key_value>--groups=<groups> --cloud
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Are you running this script on EC2 Instances?

Comment: Yes, The maintenance window pulls the script from an S3 that then runs on the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update. I found that the simplest way to differentiate was actually with the `wget` tool. It's native on AL2 but on RHEL 8 you have to install it, so I modified the script to essentially attempt to retrieve a file with `wget`, if it fails, then it proceeds with `curl` and downloads the RHEL agent file. The finished script looks like this:

```
serviceName="nessusagent"

if systemctl --all --type service | grep -q "$serviceName";then
    echo "$serviceName exists."
else

    wget "https://<bucket-name>/NessusAgent-8.2.0-amzn.x86_64.rpm" -P /tmp/nessus/

    if [ $? -ne 0 ] then

        mkdir /tmp/nessus/

        curl "https://<bucket-name>/NessusAgent-8.2.0-es8.x86_64.rpm" --output /tmp/nessus/NessusAgent-8.2.0-es8.x86_64.rpm --silent

        sudo rpm -ivh /tmp/nessus/NessusAgent-8.2.0-es8.x86_64.rpm

        sudo /sbin/service nessusagent start

        sudo /opt/nessus_agent/sbin/nessuscli agent link --key=<key>--groups=<groups> --cloud
   
    else

        sudo rpm -ivh /tmp/nessus/NessusAgent-8.2.0-amzn.x86_64.rpm

        sudo /sbin/service nessusagent start

        sudo /opt/nessus_agent/sbin/nessuscli agent link --key=<key>--groups=<groups> --cloud

    fi
fi
```

I know it's a relatively rudimentary way to accomplish this, but it suits my needs for the time crunch. I will evaluate more efficient options later down the road!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your EC2 Instances use AMIs that are properly tagged/named you could tell the OS by using EC2 Instance Metadata in conjunction with AWS CLI (this last one is optional).

As a first step, you could make a request to the [Instance Metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) to retrieve the AMI ID:

```sh
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
```

At this point, you could use the [`describe-images`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) command of the AWS CLI like so:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-1234567890EXAMPLE
```

This would return something like this:

```json
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
            "Description": "Provided by Red Hat, Inc.",
            "PlatformDetails": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux",
            "EnaSupport": true,
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "State": "available",
            "SriovNetSupport": "simple",
            "ImageId": "ami-1234567890EXAMPLE",
            "UsageOperation": "RunInstances:0010",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-111222333444aaabb",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "VolumeType": "gp2",
                        "VolumeSize": 10,
                        "Encrypted": false
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "ImageLocation": "123456789012/RHEL-8.0.0_HVM-20190618-x86_64-1-Hourly2-GP2",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "CreationDate": "2019-05-10T13:17:12.000Z",
            "Public": true,
            "ImageType": "machine",
            "Name": "RHEL-8.0.0_HVM-20190618-x86_64-1-Hourly2-GP2",
            "Tags": [
              {
                 "OS": "RHEL"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With the result above you could use the values of `Name`, `Description`, or `Tags` (if set) to decide what to do next.

If instead you don't want to rely on AWS CLI (or manage permissions to describe the images), you could simply keep a config file on S3 (which you are already using to retrieve files) with a list of AMI Ids and achieve the same result.